# Getting an error when trying to create a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating this program where you translate a DNA sequence from a file to RNA and then create a file with the RNA stored in it. I'm having this error,

```
f.write(mRNA_str)

NameError: name 'f' is not defined


from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO

Dna_Wild_str = raw_input(" Enter File :" )
Wild_Data_str = open(Dna_Wild_str)

listt = []
for record in SeqIO.parse(Wild_Data_str,'fasta'):
seq = record.seq
mRNA_str = Seq.transcribe(seq)
print "Sequence:", mRNA_str
f.write(mRNA_str)
f.close
```

Comment: Where do you open the file and assign to `f`?

Comment: Error is clear! What is `f`? probably it's a file handler that you miss to define it.

Comment: You're missing a line like `f = open("filename", "w")` You should also use `with` so you don't have to write `f.close()`

Comment: And you need to indent the body of the `for` loop, and put parentheses after `f.close`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define f in python before you try to write anything on it:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'w')
```

where filename.txt is the name and format of your file and 'w' is called mode that we use for writing in files if you want to read a file you can use 'r' mode.

You can read more at this link https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files